# Can I run a Go web server with HTML/JavaScript UI as a cross platform application (Linux, Android, iOS, macOS, Windows)

Tags: android, ios, linux, go, web

I'm experimenting with Go and as I web developer I want to explore the possibilities of building the same Go web service with the same HTML/JavaScript/CSS UI cross platform for Linux, Android, iOS, macOS, Windows and so on.

I am aware of frameworks such as Electron, Cordova, gomobile but none of them seem to work both with Go and a web UI to generate several of Linux binary, Android APK, Windows exe, macOS dmg, iOS binary (don't know that format yet) without having to code different UIs for different platforms.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking: are you looking for a library/tool to create native applications with HTML/CSS UI? If so, that's off-topic for SO. Are you just asking if you can write a cross-platform web server with Go? If so, the answer is yes.

Comment: Building go code to run on various platforms I know how to do. Question would be about a framework/method to package the go binary and static web resource files into a binary that runs the go service but also includes a "web view" that will be displayed as the apps UI. That would certainly be a question for SO.

Comment: No, looking for a framework or package is [specifically not permitted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Still this is just a question, I'm interested in that kind of discussion, feel free not to answer if you are not interested!

Comment: I'm glad you're interested in that kind of discussion, but it might be more appropriate for Reddit or elsewhere. This question should (and likely will) be closed.

Answer (score 1):

All of these platforms have browsers to render web content. Frameworks like Cordova wrap a native app around a browser component (web view).

The missing part is deploying a local go server, that would be the backend of your app. AFAIK, there is no cross platform solution for this yet.

Also, using a server locally violates it's main purposes (serving many clients concurrently, security of remotely stored information).

Comment: So what I would be looking for is then a way to expose the Go functionality to HTML and JavaScript without any HTTP involved and then package those two parts together.

Cordova as far as I understood it will not allow you to integrate against a separate binary right? Maybe I should read up more on that framework.

Comment: You can use the gomobile tool to make an SDK library, that can be used by a native app. But this method is not available for desktop platforms.

Comment: Possibly another could be to convert everything to JavaScript using GopherJS but that would feel like defeating the purpose a bit and will run slower.

Maybe there is no good way right now to do this in a cross platform way with Go (except for creating that kind of library myself).